Call async method from another async method
I am trying to run an asynchronous method from another asynchronous method and make sure that both of them complete successfully. Like in the example below I am adding a delay of 1000ms in Function1() and a delay of 3000ms in Function2(), meaning the Main() task should complete first. Also, I am using .Net6.0 to able to run this snippet.
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
                    
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inst = new SomeClass();
        // inst.Functon1(); // Method is called but not waited till its completion
        await inst.Functon1(); // Seems this blocks this Main method itself
        Console.WriteLine("finished");
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public async Task Functon1(){
        await Task.Delay(1000); // should have await to block
        Console.WriteLine("SomeClass In Func1");
        await Functon2();
    }
    
    private async Task Functon2(){
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("SomeClass In Func2");
        await Functon3();
    }
    
    private async Task Functon3(){
        Console.WriteLine("SomeClass In Func3");
    }
}

Output should be like below, in the exact same order is the expectation. If await is removed from Main(), finished is only printed but not others.
finished
SomeClass In Func1
SomeClass In Func2
SomeClass In Func3

PS - I tried calling inst.Functon1() with .ConfigureAwait(true) and ConfigureAwait(false) but it made little difference in an async method.

Why do you expect "finished" to be printed first? "Seems this blocks this Main method itself" yeah, you a-wait for it to finish before continuing. https://dotnetfiddle.net/9g0X1H

OP doesn't expect it to be printed first, they want it to be. i.e. they want Functon1 to be called async, but (in their current code) doing so means that main completes without waiting for the awaited calls.  i.e. without await Functon1 the output is just "finished".  Using await Functon1 causes main to block ("finished" is the last line of output, not the first).  They need a Task.Run wrapped around Functon1() which can be waited at the end of main (i.e. as per my answer :) )

The way you coded it, "finished" will be output last. If you want it output first, you should put it before the other calls. So your question really doesn't make sense. It's working as designed. Nor should you do what Deltics suggested in his answer - can't think of a scenario where that would be useful.

I'm unsure if the OP is telling us that they expect the current code to display finished first or if they're asking how how to make finished print first. Are they confused with the behaviour of this code or are they unsure how to modify the code to make it work in this intended way.

The expectation was clearly mentioned in the first post itself Output should be like below, in the exact same order is the expectation. . Not sure if one is taking time to read the post completely and then asking questions related to it.

@oceano1970526 - They must speak a different dialect of English in Canada than Australia - though I've thought we were very similar on that front, but maybe I'm wrong. I've read that line repeatedly and I still can and do interpret it in both ways. In the author's mind it is clear, but the reader suffers. Perhaps you would be so kind as to elucidate your thinking?

I would advice to practice or try the snippet, although it looks simple one would be surprised to how many variations that it could bring. I recently had someone from a top company on this planet argue with me as to how await is not blocking. The reason I put the snippet and the solution is to be more succinct with the question. What is worse is people have down voted such an important question to someone. I must admit that I refrained from commenting about the username as to how it relates with the comment itself, lol.

@oceano1970526 - Could you please answer my question regarding your expectation? Also, await blocks the execution of your code at the await, but it does not block the thread. It really depends what your focus is on "how await is not blocking".

The question is to be able to get the expected output with finished first of course. Having said that I would say to read the comments in the await line and the line before that? Of course feel free to fiddle around those lines to be able to get the expected output. Please let me know if it is still not clear .... :) ....

@gunr2171 ..... I like to work on creating multiple threads from the main thread, if the created threads are long running, I like them to complete whether the main thread is still running or not .... PS - I come from a non C# background and this works in other programming languages like javscript .....


Output should be like below, in the exact same order is the expectation.
finished
SomeClass In Func1
SomeClass In Func2
SomeClass In Func3


It's not possible to get this output, because the console application terminates immediately after the completion of the Main entry point. The main thread of the console application is what keeps the process alive. As soon as the main thread has nothing else to do, and provided that no other foreground threads have been launched and are still alive, the process will terminate almost immediately. So you will not get any more output after the "finished" has been printed.

I tried calling inst.Functon1() with .ConfigureAwait(true) and ConfigureAwait(false) but it made little difference in an async method.

Actually it made no difference, not little difference. The ConfigureAwait affects the behavior of an await only when there is an ambient SynchronizationContext or an ambient non-default TaskScheduler. Console applications are equipped with neither of those, as you can confirm experimentally by printing the SynchronizationContext.Current and the TaskScheduler.Current. So the ConfigureAwait has absolutely no effect in your awaits here.

Sassy, but so true!

In Console and in ASP .Net 8.0 only the TaskScheduler.Current printed to System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler. Yes, I was able to run asynchronously in ASP .Net using Parallel.ForEachAsync without await, assuming the server process was still running. If the server process stops almost right away, will the threads in Parallel.ForEachAsync complete execution.

@oceano1970526 the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is the default TaskScheduler. You can confirm this by testing for equality: TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default. Regarding fire-and-forget in ASP.NET, read this answer by Stephen Cleary. It's almost always a bad idea.

On a side note, the points here is somewhat the reflection of wealth in the real world on how it is difficult for working class or the poor to come up in society. I have only about 100 points, I first lost about 4 points and gained only 2 points in total so far, despite being a valid question and a person with about 41K needing it to answer it correctly.

@oceano1970526 well, asking a good question that will give you reputation points is not an easy task. I've asked myself questions that were perceived poorly (example), so I am talking from experience. It's generally easier to gain rep points by posting answers than asking questions.

To call the async Functon1 without blocking but still being able to await completion at some other point, you call the function without await and retain a reference to the Task that is returned.  This can then be awaited before returning from main.
Something similar to:
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inst = new SomeClass();
        var func1 = inst.Functon1();
        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        await func1;
    }

async functions return a Task, encapsulating the execution of the function itself.
Calling an async function without await is equivalent to calling a non-async function with a Task.Run wrapper:
   var task = Task.Run(() => SomeSyncFunc());

For a function marked async the Task wrapper is automatic.
By retaining the reference to the Task you gain the opportunity to await its completion at a later point from where the task is executed.
Tip
I suspect your 1s and 3s delays are intended to simulate long-running actions, but for your investigation and experimentation here, since all of the calls are awaited, this is unnecessarily slowing down your feedback cycle.
You can reduce those delays to 10ms and 30ms (or even eliminate them); it will not affect the completion order of the calls.
Fiddle
Here's a fiddle to demonstrate the solution:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inst = new SomeClass();
        func1 = inst.Functon1();
        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        await func1;
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public async Task Functon1(){
        await Task.Delay(10);
        Console.WriteLine("SomeClass In Func1");
        await Functon2();
    }
    
    private async Task Functon2(){
        await Task.Delay(30);
        Console.WriteLine("SomeClass In Func2");
        await Functon3();
    }
    
    private async Task Functon3(){
        await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("SomeClass In Func3"));
    }
}

I also modified Functon3 to make it async (albeit artificially so).  This modification demonstrates the use of a Task.Run wrapper around an otherwise synchronous call, enabling it to be awaited.
This was just to keep the linter happy about an async function containing no asynchronous code. :)

Why var func1 = Task.Run(() => inst.Functon1()); instead of var func1 = inst.Functon1()?

I was just about to post exactly the same comment. The Task.Run doesn't add any value to the code.

Because it's been 3+ years since I touched a line of C#. :)  Good catch, thanks.  I'll update the answer and fiddle.

No offence, but If it's been "3+ years since I touched a line of C#" I wouldn't be attempting to answer async questions, no matter how good your intentions are.

@Deltics - I'd be inclined to change private async Task Functon3a() { await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("SomeClass In Func3")); } to private Task Functon3b() => Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("SomeClass In Func3"));. Usually await Task.Run is just a waste of time.

@MitchWheat we are here to judge the answer, not the answerer's expertise. Despite the OP not having touched C# for 3+ years, I see nothing wrong with this answer. And this is all that matters.

@Theodor Zoulias   you're implying that that SO's reputation system is worthless?

@MitchWheat as long as we are talking about the evaluation of an answer, yes, the reputation of the answerer is irrelevant. A bad answer written by Jon Skeet is still a bad answer, and a good answer written by Joe Average is still a good answer.

@MitchWheat That contradicts what you said before that. OP might have high rep only from more than 3 years ago. Either way, we should judge the answer on its merits as currently edited.

"Calling an async function without await is equivalent to calling a non-async function with a Task.Run wrapper" isn't strictly true: without Task.Run then all code up to the first await in the function being called will run synchronously.

It makes complete sense to judge once postings based on it itself rather than ones historical data or reputation unlike what is done by AI or similar making it more rationale and relevant.
